# Issue with Mockito when mocking a method in Java Interface

Tags: mockito, junit5

I'm having issues when mocking a method in Java interface using Junit5 and Mockito 3.8. The test is failing with the reason:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
remoteCommands.getServiceStatus("ABC");
-> at com.acme.CommandHandlerTest.testServiceName(CommandHandlerTest.java:40)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

its failing at line 40 of CommandHandlerTest.java which is

```
verify(remoteCommands).getServiceStatus(serviceName);
```

However, when I debug the code, I can see the method being executed so I know there is 1 interaction with this method but Mockito can't recognise it.

Please can you advise if I am missing something? My code files are as below,

**CommandHandlerTest.java**

```java
package com.acme;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class  CommandHandlerTest {

    private CommandHandler commandHandler;
    
    @Mock
    IRemoteCommandsImpl remoteCommands;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testDoCommand_serviceName() throws RemoteException {
        commandHandler = new CommandHandler();
        
        String serviceName = "ABC";
        int mockValue = 4000;

        when(remoteCommands.getServiceStatus(eq(serviceName))).thenReturn(mockValue);
        
        commandHandler.printServiceStatus(serviceName);
        
        verify(remoteCommands).getServiceStatus(serviceName);
        
    }
}
```

**CommandHandler.java**

```java
package com.acme;

public class CommandHandler {

    private IRemoteCommands remoteCommands;
    
    public CommandHandler(){

    }

    public void printServiceStatus(String service) {

        remoteCommands = new IRemoteCommandsImpl();
        int serviceStatus = 0;

        try {
            serviceStatus = remoteCommands.getServiceStatus(service);
            System.out.println("CommandHandler->serviceStatus: "+serviceStatus);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**IRemoteCommands.java**

```java
package com.acme;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface IRemoteCommands extends Remote
{

    public int getServiceStatus(String serviceName) throws RemoteException;

}
```

**IRemoteCommandsImpl.java**

```java
package com.acme;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class IRemoteCommandsImpl implements IRemoteCommands{

    @Override
    public int getServiceStatus(String serviceName) throws RemoteException {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CommandHandler`, you create a new instance of `IRemoteCommandsImpl` and assign it to private `remoteCommands` field.

This means that your mocked `remoteCommands` is not used by object under test.

You need to restructure your code and provide `remoteCommands` to `CommandHandler`, preferably by constructor:

```java
public class CommandHandler {

    private final IRemoteCommands remoteCommands;
    
    public CommandHandler(IRemoteCommands remoteCommands) {
        this.remoteCommands = remoteCommands;
    }
    // ...
}
```

On top of that:

- you dont need `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);` if you use `MockitoExtension`